How to preload javascript chunks created after build in Nextjs?
The JS chunks created by webpack after build have a low priority and as result get downloaded late resulting in slowing down the website. I want these scripts to be loaded with high-priority, and I believe this can be done if these scripts are added with the preload attribute in the tag. I just can't seem to figure out how to do this.
Please see the screenshots.
screenshot from the network tab of console in chrome
the link tags created by next

Hi, just a side note: using images for code or errors causes a lot of problems. Use images only to illustrate graphical issues. Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.  Thank you
